# Delete word after a specific substring

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String like this:

```
"embed Test1 embed Test2 Test2.name = Foo;"
```

Now, i want to delete the "embed"s and the following word. 
In this case, "embed Test1" and "embed Test2"

My problem is, that I don't know, how many times the "embed" will occur.

The final result should look like this:

```
"Test2.name = "Foo";"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because ops lack of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this regex in replaceAll:

```
 str = str.replaceAll( "embed\\s+\\w+\\s*", "" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
String input= "embed Test1 embed Test2 Test2.name = Foo;";
String output= input.replaceAll("embed \\w+","").trim();
System.out.println(output);
```

it removes everything that starts with **embed** followed by a space followed by the next word. then it removes the spaces before and after the String, if you don't want to remove the spaces then remove the **trim()** function

Comment: +1 - Was writing an almost identical solution when you posted this.

Comment: @Rudi hehe soz mate  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `String.replaceAll(String regex,String replacement)`

Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the replaceAll  function and also a regular expression that will remove all the embed string and next to it any word character (\w) :

> String message = "embed Test1 embed Test2 Test2.name = Foo";
>     message = message.replaceAll("embed \w+", "");

Comment: I guess the OP does not know the exact words after `embed` so your solution won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
  (?:embed\s*(?:\S+)\s*)+(.*?)(.*)
```

Grab the second group.See demo.This will delete all matches of embed and word after it.

http://regex101.com/r/uR2aE4/2

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex below

Pattern

```
/(embed\s\w+\s)/g
```

Replacement:

```
''
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nG4tN6/1)